# Determining area calculations in edit session uisng ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, editing, arcgis-10.4, area

Does anybody know how to determine area calculations for polygons during an edit session using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4?

I want to be able to see the size of the polygons in hectares as I edit them or create new polygons. Ideally the area calculation would change colour if the area of the polygon falls below a specified value.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your polygons are stored in a geodatabase and are in a projected coordinate system (PCS), you could set a label expression based on the SHAPE_Area field. That field contains the area of your polygon in whatever unit your PCS uses, for example if you are using UTM with meters as the linear unit, SHAPE_Area will give area in square meters. It's also updated automatically as you edit features. You can use the label expression to convert between units, for example from meters to hectares:

```
Round(([SHAPE_Area] / 10000),1) & " ha"
```

If you want polygons less than 1 hectare to be labelled red you could create label classes as shown here. Then you would create another class for SHAPE_Area > 10000
[image]

Comment: Awesome, works and is very simple. Sometime the answer is right in front of you.

Comment: Consider marking the answer as accepted. I suggest you take the tour, at the top under the help menu. Glad this worked for you.